# Revive the Not a Robot badge on other sites?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

After becoming a Joomla Stack Exchange moderator in 2019, I asked (in the moderator Q&A) if it would be possible to bring back the [Not a Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6381/not-a-robot) badge for all SE sites.

This was a somewhat urgent request at the time because I knew I was co-organizing and speaking at an official JoomlaDay event in Brisbane that same year.  I wanted to leverage the badge offering and some free merchandise (stickers, etc) to raise public awareness of the dedicated community and generally create some additional buzz.

I don't fully know all of the rules that the badge once had, but I'd like to see it return in some fashion.

I would like for moderators to be able to attend relevant "major" offline/IRL events and be true representatives/ambassadors of their online community.  This marries well with event coordinators *wanting* to invite SE community moderators to their event as speakers.

I've given multiple talks (specifically to speak about JSE) at JoomlaDay events and I'd like to do more.  While I'm in attendance, I want to actively drive the growth of my community through energetic engagement.  Having this badge to offer potentially brings SE fans to me versus me being 100% the pursuer.

Can the Not A Robot badge be resurrected?

Comment: I don't think its ever been 'gone' - just incredibly hard to get...

Comment: I am pretty sure it's not possible for me as a representative of JSE (a non-employee).

Comment: Related (MSO): [Will there be any future events for users to earn the Not a Robot badge, or is the badge retired?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405839/will-there-be-any-future-events-for-users-to-earn-the-not-a-robot-badge-or-is-t)

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's the time, yet, to revive something that's specifically intended to encourage substantial groups of people to meet in person. I'm sure we're all looking forward to when it will be good to do that, but it doesn't feel like we're there yet. It feels like it would still be irresponsible to be encouraging such activity, at this time.

Comment: 1. Some localities in the world are more prepared than others for holding in-person events 2. If now isn't the right time, let's at least make plans for the future 3. Can the implementation of the Not a Robot scheme be implemented in an online fashion? Many online conferences have a video chat capacity. @Mak

Comment: @JourneymanGeek it's impossible to gain for any user in any automatic way, so "hard to get" isn't really accurate. The one and only way this badge is awarded is manually, when SE staff has list of people/users who attended an event so they're awarded the badge. So it's  also impossible to get for just any event that might be related to SO, unless there's something I'm missing here?

Comment: Specific requirements: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354792/3648282

Comment: @Makyen https://www.linkedin.com/posts/nicholas-morgan12345_get-over-to-the-stack-overflow-stand-at-cloud-activity-6904724871184809984-Ohyb